# node.js and mongodb-native: wait till a collection is non-empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using node.js and with the native mongodb driver (node-mongodb-native);

My current project uses node.js + now.js + mongo-db.

The system basically sends data from the browser to node.js, which is processed with haskell and later fed back to the browser again.

Via a form and node.js the text is inserted in a mongo-db collection called "messages".
A haskell thread reads the entry and stores the result in the db collection "results". This works fine.

But now I need the javascript code that waits for the result to appear in the collection results.

Pseudo code:

```
   wait until the collection result is non-empty.
   findOne() from the collection results.
   delete the collection results.
```

I currently connect to the mongodb like this:

```
    var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db;

    var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {
        auto_reconnect: true
    });
    var db = new Db('test', server);
```

My haskell knowledge is quite good but not my javascript skills.
So I did extensive searches, but I didn't get far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glad you solved it, i was going to write something similar:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
   db.collection('results',function(coll){
      coll.findOne({}, function(err, one){
        if( err ) return callback(err);
        coll.drop(callback); //or destroy, not really sure <-- this will drop the whole collection
      });
   });
} ,1000);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for you answer. I thought I could not find a solution myself so your answer would have safe me. (I am just at an implementors meeting of a open source project, so we have to code fast...).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) library.

```
var async = require('async');
globalCount = -1;

async.whilst(
    function () {
        return globalCount<1;
    },
    function (callback) {

        console.log("inner while loop");
        setTimeout(db_count(callback), 1000);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log(" || whilst loop finished!!");
    }
);
```